# How to initialize array of pointers to structures?

Tags: c

I've an array of pointers to structure.
Can i initialize all them to NULL as below??

```
struct hash
{
    int bid;
    struct hash *prev,*next,*fl,*fr;
};

struct hash *h[4]={NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL};
```

Comment: That looks like valid syntax to me.

Answer (score 7):

one NULL (or one 0) will be enough since 0 is converted to NULL when assigned to pointers

```
struct hash *h[4] = {0};
```

additional info: first element will be initialized to the first value supplied. rest will get 0 according to standards. which part, section of standards? i have no idea but you can find it somewhere in the standards.

Comment: `C11 6.7.9.19` says: _all subobjects that are not initialized explicitly shall be initialized implicitly the same as
objects that have static storage duration._ and earlier in `6.7.9.10` says: _If an object that has static or thread storage duration is not initialized
explicitly, then: — if it has pointer type, it is initialized to a null pointer;
— if it has arithmetic type, it is initialized to (positive or unsigned) zero; ..._

Answer (score 1):

Yes!

```
T *t[] = {NULL, NULL};
```

Works for each `T`.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use

```
struct hash *h[]={0,0,0,0};
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it will work

```
int main()
{
  struct hash
  {
    int bid;
    struct hash *prev,*next,*fl,*fr;
  };
struct hash *h[5]={0};
```

Comment: yeah there will be 0 not "NULL"